# Get result from list inside list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a structure like

```
class a
{
 public IList<b> bs{ get; set; }
        public class b
        {
            public string r{ get; set; }
            public IList<sl> sls{ get; set; }
            public class sl
            {
                public string sn{ get; set; }
                public string st{ get; set; }
            }
        }
}
```

the query is like if `sn == "abc"` then get `r`
I have done

```
 a aobj = new a();
 var aa = aobj.bs.Where(c => c.sl != null).Select(c => c).ToList(); // here I get `r = "qwerty", sls will have data like sn = "qwerty0", st= "1" ; sn = "asdf" , st="2"; sn = "zxc" st = "abc"; sn="me" , st = "abc"
 var bb = aa.where(c => c.sl.Select(dr => dr.st.ToLower().Contains("abc"))); // I 'm here checking that `sn` contain abc or not
 var cc = bb.Select(c => c.r).ToList(); // result
```

my expected output of query is "zxc", "me"

but I am getting all the list not only contains `abc`.. can anyone suggest me what should I do? I am partitioning this query to debug.
Thank you

Comment: First, fix your code above to compile. Second, add some data and expected results. Then it will be easier to help you out.

Comment: I think you can use `a.bs.SelectMany(c => c.sls).Where(c => c.st.Contains("abc")).Select(c=> c.sn)` ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) operator to check if an enumerable collection has an item that meets a criteria.

You can't use `Select` as that only projects an item, it isn't returning an predicate and as such has no function in a where clause.

Here is your (fixed for syntax errors) changed code:

```
var aa = aobj.bs.Where(c => c.sls != null).Select(c => c).ToList();
// use Any here
var bb = aa.Where(c => c.sls.Any(dr => dr.sn.ToLower().Contains("abc")));
var cc = bb.Select(c => c.r).ToList();
```

And here is the test set I used:

```
a aobj = new a();
aobj.bs = new List<b>();
aobj.bs.Add(new b {
  r ="bar",
  sls = new List<sl>{
    new sl { sn="tets"},
    new sl { sn="no"}
  }
});

aobj.bs.Add(new b {
  r ="foo",
  sls = new List<sl>{
    new sl { sn="no"},
    new sl { sn="abc"}
  }
});

aobj.bs.Add(new b {
  r ="fubar",
  sls = new List<sl>{
    new sl { sn="no"},
    new sl { sn="abc"}
  }
});
```

This will output:

> foo
>     fubar

If you combine all operators together you'll get:

```
var merged = aobj
   .bs
   .Where(c => c.sls != null 
      &&  c.sls.Any(dr => dr.sn.ToLower().Contains("abc")))
   .Select(c => c.r);
```

Comment: ah! Thank you sooo much.. can you tell me why can't I use select instead of `any`..basically select will select data that contain abc..m i corret?

Comment: can I put where condition in any like `.any(dr=>dr.name.where(c=>c.fn.contains("aa"))` ?

Comment: No, you can't @Dhara because you will then check for characters in `name`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a code like this:

```
var cc = a.bs
    .Where(w => w.sls?.Any(s => s.st?.ToLower().Contains("abc") ?? false) ?? false)
    .Select(c => c.r);
```